# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1- \cos (2x)}}{\sin(3x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}}{\sin(3x)}.$$

I need to solve this with out using  l'Hôpital's rule. How can I solve it?
I thought I can use the rule that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1.$$

This is what I did:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}}{\sin(3x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)}}{3\left(\frac{\sin(3x)}{3}\right)}\\
=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2\cdot 0}}{3\cdot 1}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{3} = 0.$$

I know that what I did is wrong, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Why would $\dfrac{\sin 3x}3$ tend to $1$ ?

Comment: Yves Daoust --Thanks I couldn't understand what was wrong. now it's. clear. but still I dont have a clue how to solve it.

Comment: @sara: I edited your question it seems someone also edited the question and made the square root on the whole expression but I think this version should be correct. Please check, if this is now what you intended to ask.

Comment: In the future, please avoid such crappy drafts.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig: Why did you remove the dots at the end of the equations?

Comment: Thank you. I will read the tutorial. I'm new to this site....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos 2x}}{\sin 3x}=\frac{\sqrt2 |\sin x|}{\sin 3x}\to\frac{\sqrt2}3$  for $x \to 0+0$

and

$\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos 2x}}{\sin 3x}=\frac{\sqrt2 |\sin x|}{\sin 3x}\to-\frac{\sqrt2}3$  for $x \to 0-0$.

Conclusion ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use : $\sin kx/ kx \to 1$ as $x \to 0$